# Is valgrind complaining about uninitialized variables that I have initialized?

Tags: initialization, valgrind

Valgrind is making these complaints

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==8443==    at 0x40070F: main (test.c:31)
==8443==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==8443==    at 0x4C29BCF: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8443==    by 0x4EA4847: getdelim (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==8443==    by 0x40079E: main (test.c:24)
```

Line 31 refers to the line below `if(line[i] == '(' || line[i] == '{' || line[i] == '[')` and line 24 refers to the line below `while (getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1) {`.

```
int main(){
    FILE * fp;  
    char * line = NULL;  
    size_t len = 0;  
    fp = fopen("test.json", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return 0;

    while (getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1) {
        if(!line)
            break;
        int i;

        // Go through each letter   
        for(i = 0; i<len; i++){
            if(line[i] == '(' || line[i] == '{' || line[i] == '[')
                printf("%c",line[i]);

        }    
        if(line)
            free(line);
        line = NULL;
        len = 0;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    if (line)
        free(line);
    return 1;
}
```

I've done some searching of other questions with similar problems, which made me try freeing the line at the end of the while loop and re-initializing the two variables, but I keep getting this complaint and can't figure out why.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the way you are using `getline()`.

From the manpage:

"...on a successful call, *lineptr and *n will be updated to reflect the buffer address and **allocated size** respectively."

"On success, `getline()` and `getdelim()` return the number of characters read, including the delimiter character, but not including the terminating null byte ('\0')."

It does NOT say that the amount allocated will exactly match the number of bytes read... in fact, on my system, the buffer allocated seems to always be at least 120 bytes, no matter how many characters are read into it.  I believe that is for performance reasons -- and that `getline()` will recycle the buffer as long as it is big enough before `realloc()` when it is not. Also, because getline() can reuse the same buffer on repeated calls (and will realloc the buffer if it is too small for you), your code will perform better if you don't free `line` until after the last `getline()`.

To fix your code, you will do something like this:

```
int main( void )
{
   FILE *fp;
   char *line = NULL;
   size_t len=0;
   ssize_t bytesread;
   int i,j=1;

   fp = fopen( "test.json", "r" );
   if ( fp == NULL )
      return 0;

   while ( (bytesread=getline( &line, &len, fp )) != -1 )
   { 
      // This demonstrates the point: 
      printf("line %3d len: %d bytesread: %d\n", j++, len, bytesread);

      if ( !line )
         break;

      // Go through each letter   
      for ( i = 0; i < bytesread; i++ ) {
         if(line[i] == '(' || line[i] == '{' || line[i] == '[')
            printf( "%c", line[i] ); 
      }
   }

   fclose( fp );
   free( line );
   return 0; // traditionally in C, 0 means success.  
             // if you include stdlib.h, you could use the EXIT_SUCCESS macro.
}
```